# How to put a div under sticky navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, navbar

In my index page, I use a sticky navbar also I used a JavaScript code that measures the height of screen and sticks the navbar to the bottom of the page when we open it and then when we scroll and navbar gets into the top of the page it will stick to it but after I scroll down the flipping cube goes on the sticky nav bar what should I do?

Here is an image of my problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVJXH.png)

And these are my codes

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Style the body */
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
        background: url("background.jpg");
    background-position: center;
     background-size: cover;

    background-attachment: fixed;
  transition:all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.25,0.1,0.25,1) 0s;
  -webkit-transition:all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.25,0.1,0.25,1) 0s;width:100%;
    
    
}

/* Header/logo Title */
.header {
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: center;
   color: white;
}



/* Increase the font size of the heading */
.header h1 {
    -webkit-text-stroke: 2px black;
    color: rgba(255,248,248,0.22);
}

.header p {
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

/* Sticky navbar - toggles between relative and fixed, depending on the scroll position. It is positioned relative until a given offset position is met in the viewport - then it "sticks" in place (like position:fixed). The sticky value is not supported in IE or Edge 15 and earlier versions. However, for these versions the navbar will inherit default position */
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0!important;
}

/* Style the navigation bar links */
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
    
}


/* Right-aligned link */
.navbar a.right {
  float: right;
}

/* Change color on hover */
.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Active/current link */
.navbar a.active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}

/* Column container */
.row {  
  display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE10 */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Create two unequal columns that sits next to each other */
/* Sidebar/left column */
.side {
  -ms-flex: 30%; /* IE10 */
  flex: 30%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* Main column */
.main {   
  -ms-flex: 70%; /* IE10 */
  flex: 70%;
  background-color: white;
  
}


.main::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

/* Fake image, just for this example */
.fakeimg {
  background-color: #aaa;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* Footer */
.footer {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 700px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .row {   
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 400px wide, make the navigation links stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .navbar a {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}





.container {
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 100%;
  
 
  background-color: rgb(48, 48, 48);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
    padding: 5px;
}

.flip-parent {
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1200px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  margin-bottom: -0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.flip {
  -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
  -moz-transform-origin: center bottom;
  -ms-transform-origin: center bottom;
  -o-transform-origin: center bottom;
  /* transform-origin: center bottom; */
  
  box-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 
  transform: translateY(0px);
  height: 770px;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  /* CENTER OUR CONTENT  */
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.flip:before {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#first {
  background-color: #D64541;
    float: right;
    padding: 5px;
    white-space: pre;
}

#second {
  background-color: #59ABE3;
    float: right;
    padding: 5px;
}

#third {
  background-color: #E08283;
    float: right;
}

#fourth {
  background-color: #E08283;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles.css">
    <script>
  window.console = window.console || function(t) {};
</script>
<script>
  if (document.location.search.match(/type=embed/gi)) {
    window.parent.postMessage("resize", "*");
  }
</script>
    
</head>
<body>

    
<div class="header" id="headerid">

  <h1 class="siteName" id="siteNameID">Digital World</h1>
  <p id="archID">World Best <b>architecture</b> website</p>
</div>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Services&nbsp;</a>
  <a href="projects.html">Projects</a>
  <a href="#" class="right">Contanct us</a>
</div>


    
<div class="row">
  <div class="side">
    <h2>About Me</h2>
    <h5>Photo of me:</h5>
    <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
    <p>Some text about me in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim..</p>
    <h3>More Text</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame.</p>
    <div class="fakeimg" style="height:60px;">Image</div><br>
    <div class="fakeimg" style="height:60px;">Image</div><br>
    <div class="fakeimg" style="height:60px;">Image</div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="container">
<section>
<div class="flip-parent">
<div class="flip" id="first">
<p class="pixel-counter"></p>
</div>
</div>
</section>
<section>
<div class="flip-parent">
<div class="flip" id="second">

<p class="pixel-counter"></p>
</div>
</div>
</section>
<section>
<div class="flip-parent">
<div class="flip" id="third">
<p class="pixel-counter"></p>
</div>
</div>
</section>
<section>
<div class="flip-parent">
<div class="flip" id="fourth">
<p class="pixel-counter"></p>
</div>
</div>
</section>
</div>
      
      
      <script src="https://static.codepen.io/assets/common/stopExecutionOnTimeout-157cd5b220a5c80d4ff8e0e70ac069bffd87a61252088146915e8726e5d9f147.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="rendered-js">
$(window).on('scroll', function () {

  $('.flip').each(function () {

    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
    parentElementOffsetTop = $(this).parent().offset().top,
    parentDistanceTop = parentElementOffsetTop - scrollTop;
    var elementHeight = $(this).height();
    var distanceBottom = parentDistanceTop + elementHeight;
    var opacity = distanceBottom / elementHeight;
    var rotateSpeed = (parentDistanceTop / 8).toFixed(2) * -1;

    if (rotateSpeed <= 0) {
      rotateSpeed = 0;
    } else if (rotateSpeed >= 90) {
      rotateSpeed = 90;
    }
    $(this).find(".pixel-counter").html(distanceBottom + "px is the parents bottom-               distance to top of viewport");
    $(this).css({
      "transform": " translateY(0px)  rotateX(" + rotateSpeed + "deg)",
      "opacity": opacity });

  });
});
//# sourceURL=pen.js
    </script>

      
      
  </div>
    
    
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <h2>Footer</h2>
</div>

</body>
    
    <script>
    
        if ($(window).width() < 792){
            document.getElementById("siteNameID").style.fontSize = "35px";
            document.getElementById("archID").style.fontSize = "20px";
  var x =  window.innerHeight;
   var x = x/2 - 86;
    var x = x + "px";
}
else {
    document.getElementById("siteNameID").style.fontSize = "100px";
    document.getElementById("archID").style.fontSize = "30px";
    var x =  window.innerHeight;
   var x = x/2 - 179;
    var x = x + "px";
}
    
    document.getElementById("headerid").style.paddingTop = x;
    document.getElementById("headerid").style.paddingBottom = x;
    </script>
    
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Aschkan, checkout [MDN: The stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) and [CSS z-index Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp). You need to put the navbar on top of the rest. Clue: `z-index`.

Comment: .navbar {z-index: 1} (or more...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you set z-index forexample  20 for your nav every things  stayed under it in page

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Style the body */
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
        background: url("background.jpg");
    background-position: center;
     background-size: cover;

    background-attachment: fixed;
  transition:all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.25,0.1,0.25,1) 0s;
  -webkit-transition:all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.25,0.1,0.25,1) 0s;width:100%;
    
    
}

/* Header/logo Title */
.header {
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: center;
   color: white;
}



/* Increase the font size of the heading */
.header h1 {
    -webkit-text-stroke: 2px black;
    color: rgba(255,248,248,0.22);
}

.header p {
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

/* Sticky navbar - toggles between relative and fixed, depending on the scroll position. It is positioned relative until a given offset position is met in the viewport - then it "sticks" in place (like position:fixed). The sticky value is not supported in IE or Edge 15 and earlier versions. However, for these versions the navbar will inherit default position */
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0!important;
    z-index: 20;
}

/* Style the navigation bar links */
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
    
}


/* Right-aligned link */
.navbar a.right {
  float: right;
}

/* Change color on hover */
.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Active/current link */
.navbar a.active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}

/* Column container */
.row {  
  display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE10 */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Create two unequal columns that sits next to each other */
/* Sidebar/left column */
.side {
  -ms-flex: 30%; /* IE10 */
  flex: 30%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* Main column */
.main {   
  -ms-flex: 70%; /* IE10 */
  flex: 70%;
  background-color: white;
  
}


.main::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

/* Fake image, just for this example */
.fakeimg {
  background-color: #aaa;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* Footer */
.footer {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 700px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .row {   
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 400px wide, make the navigation links stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .navbar a {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}





.container {
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 100%;
  
 
  background-color: rgb(48, 48, 48);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
    padding: 5px;
}

.flip-parent {
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1200px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  margin-bottom: -0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.flip {
  -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
  -moz-transform-origin: center bottom;
  -ms-transform-origin: center bottom;
  -o-transform-origin: center bottom;
  /* transform-origin: center bottom; */
  
  box-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 
  transform: translateY(0px);
  height: 770px;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  /* CENTER OUR CONTENT  */
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.flip:before {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#first {
  background-color: #D64541;
    float: right;
    padding: 5px;
    white-space: pre;
}

#second {
  background-color: #59ABE3;
    float: right;
    padding: 5px;
}

#third {
  background-color: #E08283;
    float: right;
}

#fourth {
  background-color: #E08283;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script>
  window.console = window.console || function(t) {};
</script>
<script>
  if (document.location.search.match(/type=embed/gi)) {
    window.parent.postMessage("resize", "*");
  }
</script>
    
</head>
<body>

    
<div class="header" id="headerid">

  <h1 class="siteName" id="siteNameID">Digital World</h1>
  <p id="archID">World Best <b>architecture</b> website</p>
</div>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Services&nbsp;</a>
  <a href="projects.html">Projects</a>
  <a href="#" class="right">Contanct us</a>
</div>


    
<div class="row">
  <div class="side">
    <h2>About Me</h2>
    <h5>Photo of me:</h5>
    <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
    <p>Some text about me in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim..</p>
    <h3>More Text</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame.</p>
    <div class="fakeimg" style="height:60px;">Image</div><br>
    <div class="fakeimg" style="height:60px;">Image</div><br>
    <div class="fakeimg" style="height:60px;">Image</div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="container">
<section>
<div class="flip-parent">
<div class="flip" id="first">
<p class="pixel-counter"></p>
</div>
</div>
</section>
<section>
<div class="flip-parent">
<div class="flip" id="second">

<p class="pixel-counter"></p>
</div>
</div>
</section>
<section>
<div class="flip-parent">
<div class="flip" id="third">
<p class="pixel-counter"></p>
</div>
</div>
</section>
<section>
<div class="flip-parent">
<div class="flip" id="fourth">
<p class="pixel-counter"></p>
</div>
</div>
</section>
</div>
      
      
      <script src="https://static.codepen.io/assets/common/stopExecutionOnTimeout-157cd5b220a5c80d4ff8e0e70ac069bffd87a61252088146915e8726e5d9f147.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="rendered-js">
$(window).on('scroll', function () {

  $('.flip').each(function () {

    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
    parentElementOffsetTop = $(this).parent().offset().top,
    parentDistanceTop = parentElementOffsetTop - scrollTop;
    var elementHeight = $(this).height();
    var distanceBottom = parentDistanceTop + elementHeight;
    var opacity = distanceBottom / elementHeight;
    var rotateSpeed = (parentDistanceTop / 8).toFixed(2) * -1;

    if (rotateSpeed <= 0) {
      rotateSpeed = 0;
    } else if (rotateSpeed >= 90) {
      rotateSpeed = 90;
    }
    $(this).find(".pixel-counter").html(distanceBottom + "px is the parents bottom-               distance to top of viewport");
    $(this).css({
      "transform": " translateY(0px)  rotateX(" + rotateSpeed + "deg)",
      "opacity": opacity });

  });
});
//# sourceURL=pen.js
    </script>

      
      
  </div>
    
    
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <h2>Footer</h2>
</div>

</body>
    
    <script>
    
        if ($(window).width() < 792){
            document.getElementById("siteNameID").style.fontSize = "35px";
            document.getElementById("archID").style.fontSize = "20px";
  var x =  window.innerHeight;
   var x = x/2 - 86;
    var x = x + "px";
}
else {
    document.getElementById("siteNameID").style.fontSize = "100px";
    document.getElementById("archID").style.fontSize = "30px";
    var x =  window.innerHeight;
   var x = x/2 - 179;
    var x = x + "px";
}
    
    document.getElementById("headerid").style.paddingTop = x;
    document.getElementById("headerid").style.paddingBottom = x;
    </script>
    
</html>
```